# MySQL driver for Rails in Windows 7 x64

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows-7

I've got problem with connecting to MySQL database on my freshly installed Windows 7 machine.
I'm getting this error when I try to migrate my database.

```
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install 
the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
193: %1 is not valid Win32 application - C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mswin32/lib/1.8/mysql_api.so
```

I currently have installed

```
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
mysql version 5.0.86  for Win64
gem 1.3.1
mysql-2.8.1-x86-mswin32
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

My colleague had a similar problem while running rails on Windows 7.
He had to replace the libmySQL.dll (in the PATH) with the one from [InstantRails](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/).

Comment: awesome, it works :) (on both Win7 and Vista machine) ... you saved my life, thx very much

Comment: Thank you! I have been unable to do rails development on windows because of this. Everything is better now.

Comment: Just FYI, the PATH referenced above is (by default) : C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\libmySQL.dll

Rename that file and replace it with the file described above.

Comment: Thanks, but what happens with the next upgrade of Rails (or MySQL)?  Do we need to keep track of random DLLs we need to drop here and there to get this to work?  Seems like a hack to me.  I'm new to RoR, and really want to experience the benefits I've heard so much about (coming from the C#, .NET world).  I understand from a high-level the benefits of an open source, light-weight language and framework (compared to Microsoft's stack), but some of the solutions to weird problems I'm researching seem very "random."  Is it me? ;)

Comment: Praise GOD. This solution works for me. Been battling with this for a while, and this got it working...just as I was about to give up :)

Comment: Warning.  I had dropped the libmysql.dll somewhere in my path and was eventually able to get `gem install mysql2` to compile.  However, when I actually went to use the gem like in `rake db:migrate` it blanched with an error similar to 'This gem is compiled for version 5.5.14 but the client library is 5.0.27`.

Answer (score 4):

I spent **hours** trying to get MySQL and Rails to play nicely on Windows (albeit XP, both 32 and 64-bit versions). I finally gave up since my production box was running Linux (on which Rails and MySQL play very nicely) and just used SQLite 3 for development. No headaches to get it working and it runs fast enough for development purposes.

However, I did hear of some people that had luck replacing one of the DLLs provided by the gem with one provided by the official MySQL distribution. Also, some people simply didn't have this DLL at all which was causing problems. In the end, it didn't work for me, but hopefully you will have more luck.

Comment: good idea about sqlite, but unfortunately, neither that works :\ see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557414/ruby-on-rails-sqlite-problem-on-windows-7-x64

Comment: @Darth - Man, that sucks. I have never had problems with SQLite. My guess is that is has something to do with 64-bit or with Windows 7, and I am on a Mac, so I can't really do any more testing. There are some other databases that Rails supports. To get you going, you might try one of them.

Comment: @Topher Fangio: Well you are unfortunately right about the Win7. The problem with sqlite was that I didn't get error about missing dll, which does show on Vista, but Win7 somehow didn't show anything (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557414/ruby-on-rails-sqlite-problem-on-windows-7-x64). Right now I'm working with SQLite on development, which works really nice, because my production server is on Linux VPS, so there is no problem. I have even more problems with image processing, which is also full of bugs on Vista x64 :( I guess this is one of the times, that make people switch OS :)

Comment: @Darth Sorry to hear that it doesn't work, but I have come to expect that from Windows. On the flip side though, my Mac went on the fritz and Java wouldn't load. After reinstalling, I finally figured out that it was a "corrupt" file in my home directory, so I guess every OS has it's quirks.

Answer (score 2):

For Rails or DataMapper or whatever to talk to MySQL you need a 32-bit driver in Rails\bin. The driver is called libmysql.dll. Even if you have a 64-bit server you need a 32-bit driver.

64-bit driver will fail will ruby/gems/1.8/gems/do_mysql-0.10.2-x86-mingw32/lib/do_mysql/1.8/do_mysql.so: 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

A wrong 32-bit version will crash with memory allocation error or something weird like that (suggested solution to take libmysql.dll from another project may not work with newer versions of MySQL).

Comment: A detailed discussion and solution to this problem is given on [installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/)

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this rails. I just have passed the same issue in vista. after downloading libmySQL.dll (in the PATH) with the one from InstantRails it starts working.

sukumaaar@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is to simply install the 32-bit version of mysql.

Comment: It doesn't have to be 32-bit version mysql. You just need 32-bit mysql connector. This issue has been discussed in detail on this link http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/ .

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward to March 2012. I solved this problem on windows 7 x64) by renaming my Ruby\b\bin\libmysql.dll and then copying libmysql.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt to Ruby\bin

There was a newer version of libmysql.dll at C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.37 but the gem didn't like the non 6.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be related to [Ruby on Rails Win7 x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966124/ruby-on-rails-win7-x64) ? If so, what was the fix again (couldn't figure it out from the first answer) ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option which has worked for me is to download the 32bit version of mysql for windows and just keep the libmysql.dll and add the location of this DLL to the windows PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the libmySQL.dll from InstantRails to a dir in my path worked for me too. It's really sad that we have to do this sort of thing though. I'd like to see the gem, or MySql itself, install this DLL properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the current versions of everything on WinXP SP3: Ruby 1.9.2p0, MySQL 5.5, mysql 2.8.1. This issue is still present and to fix it I had to copy the [Instant Rails](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/) libmysql.dll into my C:\Ruby192\bin directory. I initially copied the libmysql.dll file that came with MySQL 5.5 but that caused a seq fault!