# Ruby on Rails SQLite problem on Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sqlite

When I try to do `db:create` on sqlite database with this db config using Windows 7 x64

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000
```

I get this, kinda funny error

```
unknown error
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:29:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:29:in `dlopen'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:29:in `dlload'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:27:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:27:in `dlload'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/driver/dl/api.rb:31
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/driver/dl/driver.rb:1
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:619:in `load_driver'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:617:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:617:in `load_driver'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:72:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `new'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `sqlite3_connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/tasks/databases.rake:43:in `create_database'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/tasks/databases.rake:31
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:\Ruby\bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:\Ruby\bin/rake:19
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1
Couldn't create database for {"timeout"=>5000, "adapter"=>"sqlite3", "database"=>"db/development.sqlite3"}
```

Comment: can you create an empty file named development.sqlite3 in your db directory. run rake db:migrate and tell if that works?

Comment: @Aurélien Bottazini: nope, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by putting `sqlite3.dll` in PATH. The problem actually was, that Windows 7 didn't show me the error about missing dll. When I tried the same thing on Vista, I got error that `sqlite3.dll` was not found. But I have absolutely no idea, why this happend only on Win7