# Mysql and Ruby on Rails configuration in windows7 x86

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I install the RailsInstaller downloading from this site http://railsinstaller.org/ and also install the mysqlInstaller downloading from this site http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/. Both I have installed in c:\ drive. I have also installed mysql driver from ruby command gem install mysql. Now I haven't Idea how to configure mysql in Ruby on Rails. 
I have seen this answer [MySQL driver for Rails in Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557267/mysql-driver-for-rails-in-windows-7-x64/1584366#1584366) they tell to replace  libmySQL.dll but where to replace I didn't find such file.
Does anyone have any Idea or solution about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. following solution worked for me

Solution:
the libmysql.dll file is located in the bin directory of your mysql installation.
This file needs to be a copy of it in the Ruby\bin directory.

Comment: Ok I have copied that file.I am beginner so I need further information.From config folder in database.yml file I change Like this  development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: music_library_development
  username: root
  password: smokie3
  host:localhost
  port:3306 and save it.
But it don't generate ruby file in db folder. Now what I have to do

Comment: why you need to generate ruby file into db folder ?

Comment: when I use rake db:create it says mysql adapter i not install and I install by command: gem install mysql and mysql server running but again what's the problem.